# Installing a US tap in the UK

Tags: faucet, connectors, adapter

[image: Manufacturer spec sheet]

I purchased a faucet from the US and for love nor money can I determine what the faucets tail threaded male size requirement is that would screw into the faucet's female thread. The diagram references a 9/16" though doesnt provide any details, would anyone be be able to help me? (There doesn't seem to be a 9/16" NPT)

Thank you for any thoughts on the matter.

Once I have this I can find a adapter to connect to the British pipes

Answer (score 2):

The 9/16" connector shown in the diagram looks like the standard type of US flexible water supply line used with faucets.

The end, with rubber gasket inside, should fit a straight-threaded fitting end, presumably a 9/16" size "male compression" connection with the compression nut and ferrule removed. One just screws the remaining threaded end into the rubber-gasketed connector by hand until it bottoms out against the gasket (no teflon tape or compound used), then tightens it an additional 1/2 turn or so to compress the gasket and make a good seal. Tightening too much will distort the rubber gasket and allow leakage.

Here is a photo of an example "Compression 9/16" 14mm OD Tube to 1/2" NPT Male Pipe Brass Fitting" which would connect your connector to standard tapered thread 1/2" NPT. The nut and ferrule on the left would be discarded in your case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Threp and Armand, I'm really struggling to find a firm that will ship a flat ended 9/16". In Europe they all have non rubber/ bevelled ends. Google refuses to show any US firms and the ine I found on amazon.com would ship to the UK. I may need to bodge a 15mm which is frustrating!

Comment: this one looked like it could work? https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/163152709947?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=7Zc4cEakR0u&sssrc=4429486&ssuid=3W83e9MoTSG&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY

Comment: @DavidOgier The compression end is fine. The other end is BSPP (BSP Parallel), which is a non-tapered thread, likely also needing a matching fitting with a rubber washer. BSPT (BSP Tapered) is a tapered thread like NPT in the US, and would use teflon tape or pipe dope instead of an end-washer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, bsp is standard UK. That'll be easy to get ab adapter for. Just need to kook for one with a sensible price tag :)

Answer (score 0):

15 mm male with ptfe tape binding (or better still jointing compound) should work just fine, as long as you add a pipe anchor not far below the joint to prevent excessive movement.
Failing that, I'm pretty sure there's still 9/16" fitting sold for gas pipes in the UK. Screwfix doesn't have them, but your local boiler/gas fitter place should.

Comment: The 9/16" connector shown in the diagram looks like it has a rubber gasket inside to make a seal with the end of the incoming pipe, not with the pipe threads. Thus, it will require that pipe to have straight (not tapered NPT) threading, and no teflon tape or compound should be used. Hand tighten the connector to the point where the pipe end bottoms out on the rubber gasket, then tighten an additional 1/2 turn or so. Tightening too much will distort the rubber gasket and allow leakage.

Comment: Thank you Threp and Armand, I'm really struggling to find a firm that will ship a flat ended 9/16". In Europe they all have non rubber/ bevelled ends. Google refuses to show any US firms and the ine I found on amazon.com would ship to the UK. I may need to bodge a 15mm which is frustrating!

Comment: @DavidOgier Make sure you are asking for a 9/16" "male compression" fitting

Comment: I did just have a thought - what size thread is the other end (the one that screws into the tap itself)? If that is close enough in size to the UK standard of 10mm, just swap the entire pipe out. Probably easier than trying to find someone willing to ship across the pond.